# Computing with initial distribution and transition matrix of a finite Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a markov chain with state space $S=\{1,2\}$, initial distribution $\pi^{(0)}=\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}\right)$ and a transition matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
    0.5   &    0.5 \\
    0.3    &   0.7  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}

Find

**a)** $P(X_1=2,X_4=1,X_6=1,X_{18}=1|X_0=1)$, and

**b)** $P(X_2=1,X_7=2)$.

For the first one I'm not very sure, so I did this:

$$
\begin{align*}
P( &X_1=2, X_4=1,X_6=1,X_{18}=1|X_0=1) \\  &=P(X_1=2|X_0=1)P(X_4=1|X_3=?)P(X_6=1|X_5=?)P(X_{18}=1|X_7=?)=? \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
but I know that I can find the state $1$ or $2$ at time $n=3$ with the initial distribution and the transition matrix but I don't know which state I have to choose.

Comment: No reaction to the answer below. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your (a), you want the product  $P(X_1=2|X_0=1)\,P(X_4=1|X_1=2)\,P(X_6=1|X_4=1)\,P(X_{18}=1|X_6=1)$, as can be seen by repeated application of the Markov principle.  You must have seen matrix product ways of evaluating the individual factors like $P(X_4=1|X_1=2)$, and so on.